# Password controller update method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, forgot-password, change-password

I am trying to implement a reset password page using Devise.

What I want to achieve is to redirect the page to a different route after the password is  being updated. So, I made the change in my `passwords_controller.rb` based on [the documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb).

My Controller looks like this:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  # basic is my html.erb file for layout purpose....
  layout "basic"

  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

In my `routes.rb` file. I have included the route for password controller:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  :sessions => "users/sessions",
  :passwords => "users/passwords",
}
```

Here, I am able to access my view in `app/views/passwords/edit.html.erb`.

The problem is the `after_resseting_password_path_for` method (which is being overridden in `passwords_controller.rb`) which is not getting executed and I am redirected to the same page in my output instead of `root_path`. Also the update is not made.

Is it the problem with the update method implemented in Devise or I am missing something?

Comment: Have you verified that your password update is not failing validation?

Comment: @zeantsoi yup the email is validated properly.

Comment: Any luck with this? If the solutions provided have not addressed your question, can you update your question to provide more insight into your problem?

Comment: @zeantsoi...no hope...bro..i'll update this question...it seems like a update method failing . Otherwise my passwords should have been updated in the first go....even it is not redirected properly...

Comment: Any updates to this? Whatever additional light you could shed on what your continued problem is would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that – since you've overridden the default Devise `PasswordsController` – your `edit` action is looking to post to an `update` action in the same controller, but there is none. Try updating your custom controller to the following:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  layout "basic"

  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  def update
     render :update
  end

  def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end    

end
```

**Alternatively**, I imagine that *if* you were to specify `after_resetting_passwords_path` in your `ApplicationController`, you'd be able to bypass overriding `Devise::PasswordsController` entirely (though you'd need to conditionally set your layout in the `ApplicationController`).

Comment: +1 for the reply...i appreciate your answer. But i am afraid i'll have to specify a different view for update. In fact, I am trying to redirect it to a different path once the usual password#update method in devise is executed.

Comment: So long as you've declared your `after_resetting_password_path_for` path, this solution should work. The problem isn't that the path isn't being properly redirected to after the `update` action – it's that the `update` action is never being found in the first place (which is why your password isn't being updated). Adding the `update` action to your controller should fix things. Have you implemented this solution to see if it works?

Comment: I implemented using the super method........but didn't rendered :update since i don't have any update.html.erb file

Comment: Can you clarify? There should never be an `update.html.erb` file, since the action should redirect away. What is it not doing that you'd like it to?

Comment: I've updated my answer to display what _should_ be the full contents of your custom controller. This should 1) update your password, and 2) redirect to `root_path`, as your question specifies. If it indeed does so, would you kindly consider accepting this answer as correct?

Comment: hi buddy, i did as you told. It won't work obiviously since update view is not included inside password folder. So, it's showing an error missing template. My final outcome is to update the password via the devise update method and redirect to the root_path.

Comment: You do understand that there is virtually no cause for an update view to exist, correct? Did my answer help address your question? Is there anything else I can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

this might be help..i use this and it work..just sharing..
http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/34E99D#